# Puppet invalid parameter encoding

Tags: puppet

Trying to use puppets file_line to update /etc/environment

```
class system_variables {
  include stdlib

  file { '/etc/environment':
    ensure    => present
  } ->

  file_line { 'Add ENVIRONMENT_TYPE':
    path      => '/etc/environment',
    line      => 'ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="production"',
    match     => '^ENVIRONMENT_TYPE'
  }
}
```

But keep getting error:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/System_variables/File_line[Add ENVIRONMENT_TYPE]: Could not evaluate: Invalid parameter encoding(:encoding)
```

I have tried googling but to no avail.

**Edit:**

Ive also tested it on the master server where it runs without errors.
The file encoding is the same on both servers, and checked locales on each server aswell.

Comment: Did your stdlib installation mess up? Try reinstalling it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard i reinstalled stdlib and found that i was using version 4.10, upgraded to 4.16 and it worked. Dont know why it shouldnt work with the previous version tho considering im using file_line the same way other places in the same manifest and it works.

Comment: `encoding` was not a parameter in the older version. Based on your error message, I correctly deduced that there must have been some kind of version/code/installation conflict with your stdlib install, so i suggested reinstalling to fix any of those issues.